# Routes in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm new to Rails 3 and I need some help regarding the routes.

This is my old route

```
map.connect '/admin/login/:language/:brand',
 :controller => 'adm/auth', :action => 'login',
 :defaults => {:brand => 'brand', :language => 'en'}
```

as I change it to

```
match '/admin/login/:language/:brand', :to => 'adm/auth#login' ,
:defaults => {:brand => 'brand', :language => 'en'}
```

and also

```
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

to

```
  match "/:controller(/:action(/:id))"
  match "/:controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)"
```

but still I'm getting **No route matches [GET] "/cmm"** ,error.

I'm using Jruby 1.6.4 and rails 3.1.1

Somebody please help me!

Comment: Could you show the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: C:\dev\mysentry>rake routes

C:/dev/mysentry
  /admin/login/:language/:brand(.:format) {:brand=>"sentry", :language=>"en", 
:controller=>"adm/auth", :action=>"login"}
  /:controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)
  /:controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)

Comment: Quick question: Did you restart your server? It has to reload the routes file on startup.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the complete url you are trying to access (maybe redact the domain, if that's a secret).

Basically I'm interested in if `/cmm` is in the start of the url, therein lies your problem. As I read you routes, you have nothing matching `example.com/cmm/...`